# Group consecutive numbers together into intervals in unix

Tags: unix, ksh

I am having input in a.txt file,

```
10000030
10000029
10000028
10000027
10000026
10000024
10000023
10000021
10000018
10000018
10000017
10000016
10000015
10000014
10000013
10000011
10000010
10000009
10000008
10000006
10000005
10000004
10000003
10000002
10000001
```

I need to group the consecutive inputs together, like:

```
10000001,10000006,6
10000008,10000011,4
10000013,10000019,7
10000021,10000021,1
10000023,10000024,2
10000026,10000030,5
```

Help me solve this script.....

Answer (score 2):

First things first, you appear to have a typo in your input data. In order to get the output you desire, that first `10000018` should be a `10000019`.

Once that's fixed, you can get your desired output by passing the *sorted* file through the following `awk` script:

```
NR==1 {
    first = $0;
    last = $0;
    prev = $0;
    count = 1;
    next;
}
$0 == prev+1 {
    last = $0;
    prev = $0;
    count++;
    next;
}
{
    print first","last","count;
    first = $0;
    last = $0;
    prev = $0;
    count = 1;
}
END {
    if (count > 0) {
        print first","last","count
    }
}
```

Calling that script `data.awk` and placing your data into `data.in`, the results are as follows:

```
pax> sort data.in | awk -f data.awk
10000001,10000006,6
10000008,10000011,4
10000013,10000019,7
10000021,10000021,1
10000023,10000024,2
10000026,10000030,5
```

Elaborating on how the `awk` script works. For the first input line `NR == 1`, it simply stores the current value into `first`, `last` and `prev` (the start of the sequence, the end of the sequence and the previous line for monitoring a sequence. It also sets the current count to `1` and goes back to process the second line.

On all subsequent lines, the second section `$0 == prev+1` fires if the current line is one more than the previous. In that case it simply updates the `last` and `prev` values and increments `count`, then goes back to the top to process the next line.

Hence the third section will fire for any cases which aren't captured by the first two sections. This is any record other than the first in the input file for which the line isn't one plus the previous line. In other words, when starting a new sequence. It first prints out the details of the most recent sequence then duplicates what we did in the first section.

The `END` section fires after all lines have been processed, needed to output the details of the final sequence. Note that it outputs only if `count` is greater than zero. If `count` *is* zero, then the file was empty hence there were no sequences at all.

---

There's also a slightly shorter variant which relies on some extra conditions, joining of lines, and the fact that the sections are processed in order:

```
NR > 1 && $0 == prev+1 {
    last = $0; prev = $0; count++;
    next;
}
{
    if (NR != 1) { print first","last","count; }
    first = $0; last = $0; prev = $0; count = 1;
}
END {
    if (count > 0) { print first","last","count }
}
```

And, of course, the ultra-short (and far less readable) command line variant:

```
pax> sort data.in | awk 'NR>1&&$0==pr+1{ls=$0;pr=$0;ct++;next}{if(NR!=1){print fr","ls","ct}fr=$0;ls=$0;pr=$0;ct=1}END{if(ct>0){print fr","ls","ct}}'
10000001,10000006,6
10000008,10000011,4
10000013,10000019,7
10000021,10000021,1
10000023,10000024,2
10000026,10000030,5
```